# Why XOR gates use "=1" to indicate

Tags: circuit

As shown in the title, why do you use "=1" in the IEC symbol for XOR instead of "=2", "3", or write XOR directly. Similarly, I have the same doubts about other gate circuits.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why do you use "=1" in the IEC symbol for XOR instead of "=2"

You're talking about the IEC symbol for XOR with two inputs. `=1` is written because the output of the gate is true when exactly one of the inputs is true. If the symbol is draws with more than two inputs, then the symbol might be written with `=2` (or some other number) to indicate that the output is true when exactly two inputs (or the number given) are true. See the Wikipedia [entry on logic gate symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate#Symbols) for more information.